# Flutter golden tests hanging when running tester.waitForAssets()

Tags: flutter, svg, golden-test

When upgrading Flutter from `3.13.9` to `3.16.9`, some of our golden tests started launching timeout errors. We're using `golden_toolkit 0.15.0`, the latest version available. So latest Flutter version + latest `golden_toolkit` version.

After checking what was happening, we saw our call to `await tester.multiScreenGoldenMatcher()` lasted forever. Going deeper, we found the call that hanged the whole test was `tester.waitForAssets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

The issue was related to using `flutter_svg_provider 1.0.4`. I wasn't able to update to `1.0.7` because I had a dependency that used `http 0.13.6` while `flutter_svg_provider 1.0.7` used `http 1.1.2`.

What I had to do is to use `flutter_svg_provider 1.0.7` and override the version of `http` to `0.13.6`.

To do that, I set in my `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  http: ^0.13.6
```